# How can point my framework7-cordova based app to an external API?

Tags: cordova, single-page-application, html-framework-7

I have been trying to connect my app to an API in my cordova app. But every time I build the apk and run it, it just doesn't seem to get any requests through.

I tried adding

```
<allow-navigation href="my-api" />
```

but nothing seems to work it doesn't seem to work...or am I missing something? In the browser and postman, everthing seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Are you using https ?

Comment: @Eric No...am just using http.

Comment: You need to use https as the webview is now served from https.

Comment: Okay...let me try it.

Comment: @Eric it worked. Thanks a lot mate. I love you